# Using QMI interface modem on Android AOSP to setup data connection

Tags: android, embedded-linux, android-source, libqmi

I have a modem with QMI interface, it enumerates to /dev/cdc-wdm0 and network interface wwan0. 
I installed libqmi on my Linux machine and I am able to setup data on interface wwan0 using qmicli. I have followed following steps:

1) sudo ifconfig wwan0 down
2) echo 'Y' | sudo tee /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip
3) sudo ifconfig wwan0 up
4) sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-net='net-raw-ip|net-no-qos-header' --wds-start-network=apn=myInternet --client-no-release-cid
5) sudo udhcpc -i wwan0

It works perfectly fine. Now I want it to port to my Android AOSP. I have configured kernel support and it enumerates to /dev/cdc-wdm0 and network interface wwan0 correctly.
I have searched the internet but didn't find libqmi for Android.

What I have found is [uqmi tool](https://github.com/rpetrovski/android-x86-external-uqmi) but I am unable to build it in the Android source. I want help if there is an easy tool on Android as qmicli is on Linux, if uqmi is what I need, then please guide me how to build it in Android source. Thanks

Regards,
Muhammad Awais

Comment: Did you find a tool? I am trying to integrate a Quectel modem onto an android platform.

Comment: unfortunately not. Did you find something?

Comment: i never got it to work - i could get it to boot, but then it would crash when enabling the modem